# vba Regular Expression to determine a case for a loop

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to determine a case in a loop using a regular expression. I have a text file that looks like:

```
Username     : 1110491103121002@mil   Index        : 130   
Assigned IP : xxx.xx.xx.xxx          Public IP    : xxx.x.xxx.xx  
Login Time   : 08:27:04 MST Tue Mar 24 2020  
Duration     : 1h:33m:00s  
Inactivity   : 0h:20m:46s  
Username     : 1254709600121004@mil   Index        : 145 
Login Time   : 09:40:14 MST Tue Mar 24 2020  
Duration     : 0h:19m:50s 
Inactivity   : 0h:00m:00s  
Username     : 1362984650@mil   Index       : 182  
Assigned IP  : xxx.xx.xx.xx           
Public IP   : xx.xxx.xxx.xx  
Login Time   : 09:13:38 MST Tue Mar 24 2020  
Duration   : 0h:46m:26s  
Inactivity   : 0h:00m:00s
```

As you can see, in some blocks there is no entry for Assigned IP and Public IP. I'm trying to turn this into a tab delimited file so I've written a loop in VBA (I've tried both Excel and Access - I don't care which one this happens in) that will find all headers (e.g. "UserName", "Index" etc.) and the accompanying spaces and replace them with tabs. That works great when a block has all the rows. What I'm trying to do is determine if the line that follows the index number begins with an A or an L. If it starts with an A then nothing (do the next step in the code) but if it starts with an L then insert two tabs then move on. Ultimately this will be imported to either a spreadsheet or Access table (either tool is acceptable), I just need to get it formatted properly in the text file first.

Again, I'm doing fine with the replace part. What I'm struggling with is to identify that. I've written the regex as `"Index *: [0-9]{1,6}[\r\n]L"`. I NEVER get a match, though.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: For some reason this is not showing that there's a line break between Index:  145 and "Login Time" but in the text file it's there.

EDIT:  What it looks like now:

```
Username     : 1254709600121004@mil   Index        : 145<CR><LF>
Login Time   : 09:40:14 MST Tue Mar 24 2020  

 What I want:
1254709600121004@mil vbTab 145 vbTab vbTab vbTab 09:40:14 MST Tue Mar 24 2020
```

Comment: `{1-6}` is a malformed limiting quantifier, it should be `{1,6}`. `[\r\n]` matches a single line break char, but if you have CRLF endings, you need to match two line break chars. However, I do not see any line breaks between `Index : 145` and `Login`. Please provide a string and expected output.

Comment: You're right, that was a typo - I AM using {1,6}

Comment: So, you need `Index *: *[0-9]{1,6}[\r\n]+L`, right?

Comment: There's only ever a single space between the colon and the beginning of the number. But yes - am I only missing the plus? Is that my problem?

Comment: Maybe. Try.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just doing the Regex as an intermediary step before importing the nicely formatted data, you may want to try just importing it straight into Access. I've put together a small bit of VBA code that runs successfully over your sample data:

```
Sub sGetIPData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strDummy As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblRegex WHERE 1=2;")
    strFile = "J:\downloads\regex.txt"
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As intFile
'   start by adding the first record
    rsData.AddNew
    Line Input #intFile, strInput
    strDummy = Left(strInput, InStr(strInput, "Index") - 1)
    strDummy = Mid(strDummy, 16)
    rsData!UserName = Trim(strDummy)
    strDummy = Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, "Index") + 1)
    strDummy = Mid(strDummy, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1)
    rsData!Index = Trim(strDummy)
    Do
        Line Input #intFile, strInput
        If Left(strInput, 8) = "Username" Then
'   insert the record that we have just finished with
            rsData.Update
'   and now add the next record
            rsData.AddNew
            strDummy = Left(strInput, InStr(strInput, "Index") - 1)
            strDummy = Mid(strDummy, 16)
            rsData!UserName = Trim(strDummy)
            strDummy = Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, "Index") + 1)
            strDummy = Mid(strDummy, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1)
            rsData!Index = Trim(strDummy)
        ElseIf Left(strInput, 8) = "Assigned" Then
            If InStr(strInput, "Public IP") > 0 Then
                strDummy = Trim(Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1))
                strDummy = Left(strDummy, InStr(strDummy, "Public") - 1)
                rsData!AssignedIP = Trim(strDummy)
                strDummy = Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, "Public"))
                strDummy = Trim(Mid(strDummy, InStr(strDummy, ":") + 1))
                rsData!PublicIP = strDummy
            Else
                rsData!AssignedIP = Trim(Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1))
            End If
        ElseIf Left(strInput, 5) = "Login" Then
            rsData!LoginTime = Trim(Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1))
        ElseIf Left(strInput, 8) = "Duration" Then
            rsData!Duration = Trim(Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1))
        ElseIf Left(strInput, 10) = "Inactivity" Then
            rsData!Inactivity = Trim(Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1))
        ElseIf Left(strInput, 6) = "Public" Then
            rsData!PublicIP = Trim(Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, ":") + 1))
        Else
            Debug.Print "Unknown: " & strInput
        End If
    Loop Until EOF(intFile)
'   finally add the current record
    rsData.Update
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Reset
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sGetIPData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

There are probably are a few more checks that are needed, but it may help you.

Regards,

Comment: This is AWESOME, let me try it on my entire data set. Thank you!!

Comment: It WORKS, it WORKS!!! Woohoo! I will have to cast the index as an int and the Login Time, Duration and Inactivity to date/time but other than that this is PERFECT. Thank you, thank you, thank you! I'd upvote 32 times if I could, lol, but it won't let me even once.

Comment: Oops, and it's showing Assigned IP and Public IP in the same field. I'll take a look at that, as well.

Comment: If the 2 IP values are being stored in the same field, it may be that the data is on the same line in some cases. In which case when checking for the data starting with Assigned/Public, you will need to add an additional check using `InStr` to see if the other IP is there as well, and if so, use some string manipulation to get the two different IP addresses.

Comment: Code has been modified to deal with the Public IP following on the same line from Assigned IP. If Assigned IP can also follow Public IP on the same line, then that section of code would need to be modified as well.

Comment: And now it quit working. :-(  It's now reading the strInput as "ï»¿" instead of UserName. I've looked repeatedly at the text file and, while it does begin with two lines I want to skip (a blank line and then a line that identifies the concentrator the log comes from), neither of them nor the beginning of the actual data has those characters. I've tried converting the text file to different collations (UTF-8, ANSI, etc) and I don't see those characters anywhere in there.

Comment: Hmm. So, the code works on the original data, but on some different data it doesn't. That sort of implies that there is something slightly different with this new set of data that wasn't expected. It is probably worth narrowing down where this is happening in the data file, and then opening it up in something like Notepad++ to see if that shows anything up.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I opened it in Notepad++ to look for any extraneous characters. There weren't any. It might be useful for me to note that I did two things at once (bad Idea, I know). I started using the new code with the IP block AND I started running it against the full data set (instead of just a few blocks).AND, going forward this will be run against a .dat file instead of .txt - I just couldn't see into the .dat for troubleshooting and testing purposes.

Comment: You need to identify where this odd data is. Paste it into a new text file, and then read the whole file into Access (using `strInput = Input(LOF(intFile), intFile)`) and then walking the string character by character (using `Debug.Print Asc(Mid(strInput, lngLoop1, 1))` in a Loop. This may give you enough information to work around the problem.